# How to add number of custom tab in product info detail tab?

Tags: magento2, product-tab, product-details

I added 3 custom tab in product info detail tab page

```
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom1.tab" as="custom1"  template="product/view/custom1.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">custom1</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>                  

        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom2.tab" as="custom2"  template="product/view/custom2.phtml" group="custom2" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">custom2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom3.tab" as="custom3"  template="product/view/custom3.phtml" group="custom3" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">custom3</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

and i call .phtml in seperate files. Frontend gets only "custom3" tab which i placed in last line in .xml file.

Please let me know the corrections in this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way :-

```
<referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom1.tab" as="custom1"  template="product/view/custom1.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">custom1</argument>
            <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>                  

    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom2.tab" as="custom2"  template="product/view/custom2.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">custom2</argument>
             <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>

    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom3.tab" as="custom3"  template="product/view/custom3.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">custom3</argument>
             <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">30</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

add

> `group="detailed_info"`  in all tab

Comment: @Bhurio, I tried above the way, but it's too getting same formate

Comment: Please add sort_order like this :  <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>  please see my edited answer

Comment: See my code again.

Comment: Please let me clarify, in your code 1st line is "<block ...> tag or else <referenceblock ...> tag?

Comment: Ohh My Bad ..,,, I am sorry .it's referenceblock.

Comment: Thank you, let me check and let you know

Comment: Now i got it, thank you :)

Comment: Ok Thanks...........

Comment: Hi, my default more information tab was missing.

Comment: Please add additional attribute in your product from admin side like dataenrty of attribute , the more information tab is showing automaticallly....